# Fast method to pivot_table() and concatenate in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code:

```
counter = 0
for assignid in tqdm(selectedTests['assignids'].unique()):
    selectedTestsForAssignID = selectedTests[selectedTests['assignids']==assignid]
    for memberid in selectedTestsForAssignID['memberid'].unique():
        selectedTestsPivotCorrectTemp = selectedTestsForAssignID[selectedTestsForAssignID['memberid']==memberid].pivot_table(index=['memberid'],
                                                                                                                 columns=['col1', 'col2'],
                                                                                                                 values='col3', aggfunc=np.max)
        if counter == 0:
            selectedTestsPivotCorrect = selectedTestsPivotCorrectTemp
        else:
            selectedTestsPivotCorrect = pd.concat([selectedTestsPivotCorrect, selectedTestsPivotCorrectTemp], axis=0, join='outer')
        counter = counter + 1
```

In the above code, I'm trying to create a pivot table for each `memberid` and concatenating to a master pivoted table called `selectedTestsPivotCorrect`. I have a total of 1000 `assignids` and each `assignid` would have an average of 20-25 `memberids`. The number of columns after pivoting for each `memberid` should be around 30, on average.

Even though this code works just fine, it runs quite slow. It takes in excess of 1.5 hours to run. I have a feeling that this can be done in a much more efficient manner, but I don't know how.

I also tried creating the pivot table for each assignid in one shot (not iterating over each `memberid`), but that usually gives me one or the other error, which, upon googling, I found was related to memory issues.

The code starts taking longer to execute after a few iterations on `assignids`, as the master pivot table becomes larger.

All said and done, I would like to create a pivot table that has `memberid` as index, `['col1','col2']` as columns, and `col3` as values.

Any suggestions to make this code run faster are highly appreciated.

TIA.

Comment: having to work out each unique value, then iterating over each one isn't very efficient. Can you post the error you get when you do a single pivot_table? I wouldn't have thought 1000 * 15 rows would take that much memory.

Answer (score 0):

Why exactly do you do nested loop? The point of `pivot_table` is that you don't need to do so:

```
df.pivot_table(index=['assignid', 'memberid'],
               columns=['col1', 'col2'],
               values='col3',
               aggfunc='max')
```

Does `groupby().agg().unstack()` work for your?

```
(df.groupby(['assignid', 'memberid', 'col1', 'col2'])
     ['col3'].max()
     .unstack(['col1','col2'])
)
```

I tested several times and it look like `pivot_table`.